# Use of ‘or’ when it means ‘and’ in negatives

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does negation affect the use and understanding of “or” and “and”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26423/how-does-negation-affect-the-use-and-understanding-of-or-and-and)

If I want to negate a sentence such as

> I like beer and whiskey. [Most commonly understood as, I think, *I like beer and I like whiskey*.]

I have to convert the *and* to an *or*:

> I don't like beer or whiskey.

There's no sense of an *or* in the second sentence, so its inclusion seems a bit perverse. I realise that I could say

> I don't like beer and whiskey.

but that would mean something different:

> I don't like (beer and whiskey).

rather than the intended

> (I don't like beer) and (I don't like whiskey).

So my question is: what's going on here? Why do we have to make this change?

Comment: A formal statement of the way this works is De Morgan's Laws in Boolean algebra: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: isn't it supposed to use 'nor' like `I don't like beer nor whiskey`

Comment: @Phelios You are thinking of "I like neither beer nor whiskey."

Comment: Technically correct but practically unused is 'I like beer nor whiskey', meaning I don't like either.

Comment: Not yet pointed out: "Beer and whiskey" might be some kind of combination, which you're either liking or not liking all-together-in-one-glass. "Or" makes it clear that you're talking about two separate things; "And" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's as clear cut as you make out. If I wanted to know if you liked those two drinks, I might ask 'Do you like beer or whiskey?' And you could say 'I don't like beer and whisky' and be understood. Both conjunctions can be used; context will determine their meaning.

Answer (score -1):

*And/or* is part of the general discussion, called Boolean operations. On the base ground of your own reasoning, we can also interpret

> I like bear and whiskey

as

> I like (bear and whiskey)

in which *bear and whiskey* is interpreted as a combination, not as different individual things.

It's more like saying

> I like coffee and sugar.

In this statement, the listener/reader doesn't interpret *coffee* and *sugar* as two different things. Though when we want to denote the combination, we usually use *with*, like saying

> I like coffee *with* sugar

but still using *and* makes us interpret the two things as a combination (This was all based on your own reasoning for negative interpretation).

So, what happens here is that the listener either interprets the phrase as *a combination of two things*, or *two individual things* and the and/or doesn't make this interpretation. I believe that it's the context which differentiates the interpretations.

Thus, all of the sentences you mentioned are valid enough to be perceived as either one of the interpretations, and nothing magical happens here.

Comment: What are all those bears doing with the whiskey, hey?

Comment: The bear will steal your whiskey.